# Why connected with linux we under the /root directory?

Tags: linux

When I connect with the Linux, I am under `/root` library.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls
anaconda-ks.cfg   packstack-answers-20170515-095857.txt
keystonerc_admin  tmp-packstack-answers-20170515-095856.txt
keystonerc_demo
```

There is two questions:

1. Why in `/root` there is `~` in the `[root@localhost ~]` but not the root?

   Because if I in `/tmp`, this is `[root@localhost tmp]#` .
2. Why connected with linux, I am under the `/root`, but not the `/`, if there is something convenient for us to config, where is the benefits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you log in to your `home directory` which is defined in your password file (`/etc/passwd`).

The `~` simply indicates that you are presently in your home directory and can also be used as a shortcut.  If you want to go in your `something` directory which is inside your home, you can `cd ~/something`.

You **do not** want to log in any public directory for security reasons because of your profile configuration and connection logs for example.

It is not inconvenient to change directories (`cd`).